# Java packages com and org

Tags: java, package, naming-conventions

What are the meaning of the packages `org` and `com` in Java?

Answer (score 132):

According to [Sun](http://java.sun.com/docs/codeconv/html/CodeConventions.doc8.html), packages should be namespaced according to the inverse of your domain name, and then followed by whatever you see fit. Most companies or organisations have a `.com`, or `.org` domain name, and hence most packages start with `com.` or `org.`. To quote from the [Sun Code Conventions](http://java.sun.com/docs/codeconv/html/CodeConventions.doc8.html):

> The prefix of a unique package name is always written in all-lowercase ASCII letters and should be one of the top-level domain names, currently com, edu, gov, mil, net, org, or one of the English two-letter codes identifying countries as specified in ISO Standard 3166, 1981.
>
> Subsequent components of the package name vary according to an organization's own internal naming conventions. Such conventions might specify that certain directory name components be division, department, project, machine, or login names.

And the examples that they give, make it pretty clear that you are meant to use the companies DNS name:

> com.sun.eng
>
> com.apple.quicktime.v2
>
> edu.cmu.cs.bovik.cheese

You will also see `edu.` and `net.` packages out [in the wild](http://pmd.sourceforge.net/ant-task.html) as well, although they are less common.

Comment: What if the company changes domains?

Comment: @LeonardoRaele Typically in this case then you enter a world of pain ;-) More seriously, there are two options, rename all classes, which can work if the code is internal anyway, or leave it using the old name, since that will probably still be unique anyway.

Comment: What is the best naming convention for when you're not part of an organization or don't have a website? I've seen `me.username` suggested before but I'm not sure if that's the best or the only standard.

Comment: @AaronFranke I've seen people use their GitHub username as their domain, so, for example: com.guthub.pwagland.xxx the primary purpose is to get a unique name, so that you don't have to change it, and it will never conflict with the name that someone else has chosen.

Comment: what if your company has 2 domains i.e. wordpress.com and wordpress.org

Comment: @JanacMeena then just choose one of them.

Answer (score 49):

You can also see package names as reversed internet domain names (which is often also true in real world, see for example the `org.apache.commons` which correlate with http://commons.apache.org). The [`com` (commercial)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/.com) and [`org` (organization)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/.org) are here then actually [Top Level Domain](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Top-level_domain) names.

Package names are in general just to identify the manfacturer/vendor of the code you're facing.

Comment: And to ensure package name uniqueness. I Think it is a pretty smart Way to do it

Comment: I may be wrong, but com sounds unnecessary at this point if everyone is going to use it. I'd rather just use the company name by itself. I prefer the naming system that they have for other packaging systems like npm and composer. They use 'username/packageName' or something similar. So I would name my packages in java as 'username.packagename'

Answer (score 11):

Usually `com` is used by companies when naming the packages, `com` being followed by the company's name. For instance you have the `com.sun` packages in the JVM.

The `org` package prefix is mostly used by non-profit organizations or for open source code, such as apache, w3c, etc.

Comment: The convention of using a comapany's .com URL for internal code and .org for any code made public is a good idea. That's what I summarized from this answer.

Comment: Dennis, I don't think it would be a good idea. It means that releasing the code would change package names and would break the internal software that is using the original names. Also, there would be a namespace collision if example.com and example.org are owned by different companies and both want to release Java code.

Answer (score 5):

See [Oracle doc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/package/namingpkgs.html) for package naming

See [Naming Conventions](https://www.safaribooksonline.com/library/view/java-8-pocket/9781491901083/ch01.html) for class/interface/annotations/etc standard naming

> package name and class standard syntax:
>  
>   **<your domain in reverse>.<project name>.<controller/dao/service/handlers etc>.<your class>**

*example1:* (here domain:-
 "stackoverflow.com", project:- "Test")
 **com.stackoverfllow.test.handler.TestHandler**

example2: (here domain:- "www.google.co.in", project:- "My Proj")
 **in.co.google.myproj.controller.MainController**

> but for reserved domains like java.*, javax.*, sun.*, etc. you should
>   get **permission** from oracle community

Answer (score 0):

These package names are due to the officially recommended convention of using your organization's reverse domain name as the package prefix.  For instance, code written by an organization which owns and uses `example.com` would use `com.example` as the package name prefix.

Since `com` and `org` are very common top level domain names, they are very frequently seen as the top-level package in most libraries.

Following this recommendation ensures software written by different organizations won't have conflicting class names when used together, since they will have different package names and therefore all classes will have different fully qualified class names.

This recommendation and the reasons for this are documented in the [Java Language Specification](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se21/html/jls-6.html#jls-6.1) (JLS):

> Naming Conventions
>
> The class libraries of the Java SE Platform attempt to use, whenever possible, names chosen according to the conventions presented below. These conventions help to make code more readable and avoid certain kinds of name conflicts.
>
> […]
>
> Package Names and Module Names
>
> Programmers should take steps to avoid the possibility of two published packages having the same name by choosing unique package names for packages that are widely distributed. This allows packages to be easily and automatically installed and catalogued. This section specifies a suggested convention for generating such unique package names. […]
>
> If unique package names are not used, then package name conflicts may arise far from the point of creation of either of the conflicting packages. This may create a situation that is difficult or impossible for the user or programmer to resolve. […]
>
> You form a unique package name by first having (or belonging to an organization that has) an Internet domain name, such as oracle.com. You then reverse this name, component by component, to obtain, in this example, com.oracle, and use this as a prefix for your package names, using a convention developed within your organization to further administer package names. […]
>
> […]
>
> The first component of a unique package name is always written in all-lowercase ASCII letters and should be one of the top level domain names, such as com, edu, gov, mil, net, or org, or one of the English two-letter codes identifying countries as specified in ISO Standard 3166.