# Which package name should I use for open source java library?

Tags: java, open-source, package

I'd like to release an open source java library. I thought of using my last name as package name but I find that a bit weird. I'd like to use something more neutral like 'open.libname'.

Are there any recommendations on open source java package naming?

Comment: Close voters: there actually is an authoritative answer for "How should I name my Java packages?", using the reverse domain names described in the answers (see the notes at the end of [Java Language Specification section 6.1](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-6.html#jls-6.1)).  I voted to close with a duplicate providing a good answer, but whose question doesn't exactly match this one  -- if you know of a better duplicate, please use it instead.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Java packages com and org](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2125293/java-packages-com-and-org)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

As the others said, start the package name with the reversed domain name:

Register a domain such as myproject.org and then use `org.myproject.mymodule`.

Or, if you don't have your own domain use the sub-domain where you host the code, e.g. if you host the code on myproject.sourceforge.net, use `net.sourceforge.myproject.mymodule`.

Comment: `net.sf` is a nice short prefix, if [sourceforge.net](http://sourceforge.net) is chosen for hosting. [sf.net](http://sf.net/) is a domain registered by sourceforge.net.

Comment: I liked your suggestion. In my case it would be a awkard 'com.google.code.mylibrary' since this is not a google official code release. Alternatives?

Comment: @Gatis Did you see my suggestion of `com.googlecode.` in my answer? `googlecode.com` points to `code.google.com`.

Answer (score 4):

The usual recommendation is to prefix your package with the name of a domain you own in reverse order: `com.mydomain.mypackage`. Since you own the domain, the chances of name collisions are reduced.

Also, a better choice for the package name is something that reflects the functionality of the package, rather than your own name. What will you use when you want to release your second (and perhaps totally unrelated) library?

Comment: You mean something like gatis.foo and gatis.bar for libraries foo and bar?

Comment: Yes. If you own a domain like gatis.com, you could use package names `com.gatis.foo` and `com.gatis.bar`. Don't go overboard, but the more you can make your package names unique, the less chance of problems from name collisions. (In many cases, the choice of package name isn't really important, but that's different when distributing a library. Also, places like Android Market use the package name of the launch class to identify apps.)

Answer (score 3):

Where are you hosting your project? When I host a project on Google Code, for example, I tend to use `com.googlecode.project-name` (it seems rude to use `com.google.code.project-name`). I don't actually know what Google thinks about this, but it follows the example of many Sourceforge.net projects. If you have a personal/corporate domain then go ahead and use that one, of course.

Answer (score 2):

This may or may not be the answer you're looking for.

The common convention is to reverse your personal/company domain name and prepend it to whatever the name of the package is.

So, if your domain is "www.feel.com" and your package name is "mypackage", then your fully qualified package name would be: `com.feel.mypackage`

Comment: [Package naming conventions](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_package#Package_naming_conventions) are that everything is lower case.

Comment: @Ted thanks for the reminder, just updated. I've been away from Java for too long...