# Application Bundle Name in Segment

Tags: android

i have a problem in android application package installation,
why android must have two segment of package name, 
why i can't use single Name as Package name.

Now:"**com.alert.myalert**"
  Need:"**myalert**", in my application i required when my app is installed in device, it shows only my app name, when the user have to check in **Settings->App->myalert**. This is my problem, i can't get that now showing **Settings->App->com.alert.myalert**. kindly help me, Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have an explanation about this [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2125298/1668144), it's just a convention to keep the names of your packages like the reverse of your domain.

From SUN Convention:

> The prefix of a unique package name is always written in all-lowercase
>   ASCII letters and should be one of the top-level domain names,
>   currently com, edu, gov, mil, net, org, or one of the English
>   two-letter codes identifying countries as specified in ISO Standard
>   3166, 1981.
>
> Subsequent components of the package name vary according to an
>   organization's own internal naming conventions. Such conventions might
>   specify that certain directory name components be division,
>   department, project, machine, or login names.

Comment: Hi Merino, My client need to show his app, just like WhatsApp,TempleRun

Comment: why you could not follow the convention? there is any problem in just calling it com.yourname.myalert?

Comment: Because, my client don't want to show the bundle name in Settings

Comment: Merino, do you have any idea about how to hide the segments.

Comment: tell your client that this is the right way to show it :)

Comment: fine thank u. Because i'm a new to Android Development, so that's why i can't get idea clearly. Now i'm okay. Thank u very much Merino.