# "com" at the start of every Maven groupid

Tags: java, maven, naming-conventions

What is the meaning of "com" at the beginning of (almost) all maven groupid's?

Should I do the same with my personal or internal company projects?

**edit:** Thanks to @Berger, I found the [fitting question here on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2125293/java-packages-com-and-org)
So this question could be marked as duplicate or be deleted.
Thanks.

Comment: It's a convention to use the reverse of the domain name of your company as a basis for your groupId. So if you work for `example.com`, your groupId should probably be `com.example`, possibly with further keywords for grouping purposes if need be

Comment: It is not quite a duplicate, the other question is about java package names. Sure Maven chose to follow the same convention, but your question may remain relevant as a question about Maven's `groupId` per se .

Answer (score 3):

From Maven's [Naming Conventions](https://maven.apache.org/guides/mini/guide-naming-conventions.html) :

> **groupId** will identify your project uniquely across all projects, so we
>   need to enforce a naming schema. It has to follow the package name
>   rules, what means that has to be at least as a domain name you
>   control, and you can create as many subgroups as you want. Look at
>   More information about package names(*). eg. `org.apache.maven`,
>   `org.apache.commons`
>
> A good way to determine the granularity of the **groupId** is to use the
>   project structure. That is, if the current project is a multiple
>   module project, it should append a new identifier to the parent's
>   groupId.
>
> eg. `org.apache.maven`, `org.apache.maven.plugins`,
>   `org.apache.maven.reporting`

(*) :
Then from the [Naming Conventions](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/codeconventions-135099.html) in Java  for packages :

> The prefix of a unique package name is always written in all-lowercase
>   ASCII letters and should be one of the top-level domain names,
>   currently `com`, `edu`, `gov`, `mil`, `net`, `org`, or one of the English
>   two-letter codes identifying countries as specified in ISO Standard
>   3166, 1981.
>
> Subsequent components of the package name vary according to an
>   organization's own internal naming conventions. Such conventions might
>   specify that certain directory name components be division,
>   department, project, machine, or login names.

Also have a look at this question : [Java packages com and org](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2125293/java-packages-com-and-org)